# Reading off connection 1-forms from Cartan's structural equation $de=-\omega\wedge e$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, connections, semi-riemannian-geometry

Suppose we have a Lorentzian metric of the form
\begin{align}
g&=-f(r)^2\,dt^2+ h(r)^2(dr^2+r^2\,d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2\theta\,d\phi^2)
\end{align}
Where $f,h$ are say strictly positive functions. We use the Levi-Civita connection. I introduced the 1-forms
\begin{align}
e^0=f(r)\,dt,\quad e^1=h(r)\,dr,\quad e^2=rh(r)\,d\theta,\quad e^3=rh(r)\sin\theta\,d\phi
\end{align}
which diagonalize the metric, and now I'm trying to use these to calculate the connection 1-forms $\omega^a_{\,b}$ using Cartan's structural equation $de=-\omega\wedge e$ (since Levi-Civita connection is torsion free).

---

**Question 1.**

The issue I'm facing is that once I calculate $de$, I'm not sure how to identify $\omega$ from those equations: initially I tried the most naive thing by just looking at the appropriate coefficient and calling that the appropriate component of $\omega$, but I think this naive approach is wrong, probably because the wedge-product of non-zero forms can still be zero (so "cancelling" terms won't work).

To be more explicit, I calculated
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
de^0= f'(r)\,dr\wedge dt\\
de^1= 0\\
de^2=(h(r)+rh'(r))\,dr\wedge d\theta\\
de^3= (h(r)+rh'(r))\sin\theta\,dr\wedge d\phi+ rh(r)\cos\theta\,d\theta\wedge d\phi
\end{cases}
\end{align}
When I first did the calculation, I naively concluded that
\begin{align}
de^0=f'(r)\,dr\wedge dt=-\left[-\frac{f'(r)}{f(r)}\,dr\right]\wedge e^0,
\end{align}
and thus that $\omega^0_0=-\frac{f'(r)}{f(r)}\,dr, \omega^0_1=\omega^0_2=\omega^0_3=0$. Next, from $de^1=0$ I naively concluded that $\omega^1_{\,b}=0$ for all $b=0,1,2,3$. I did a similar thing with the other equations. But now I realize this is wrong, because for example, we can also write
\begin{align}
de^0=f'(r)\,dr\wedge dt=
-\left[\frac{f'(r)}{h(r)}\,dt\right]\wedge e^1,
\end{align}
so if I were to use my above logic, I would have $\omega^0_0=0, \omega^0_1=\frac{f'(r)}{h(r)}\,dt, \omega^0_2=\omega^0_3=0$. So clearly my mistake stems from the fact that the wedge of non-zero forms can be zero. But now I'm not sure what the correct approach is.

I have read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3725231/568204) by @Ted Shifrin, and it seems like the correct answer is the second approach, but I'm not sure why. Also, I can't really understand that answer because it's not clear to me why certain certain $\omega^a_b$ are equal to certain functions and why others are multiples of some $e^i$, and why some others are zero.

---

**Question 2.**

The equation $de=-\omega\wedge e$ consists of four equations relating $2$-forms. However, $\omega$ being a $4\times 4$ matrix (in this case) of $1$-forms, consists a-priori of 16 unknowns. I believe in this case due to the Lorentzian signature and the diagonalizability of the metric, there is some relationship between $\omega^a_b$ and $\omega^b_a$, so that it can be written as
\begin{align}
[\omega^a_b]&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&\alpha_1&\alpha_2&\alpha_3\\
\alpha_1&0&\beta_1&\beta_2\\
\alpha_2&-\beta_1&0&\beta_3\\
\alpha_3& -\beta_2&-\beta_3&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
for some 1-forms $\alpha_1,\beta_i$. So, now there are only 6-unknowns, but this is still too many  unknowns for the number of equations.

So my question is whether we can always use this structural equation to determine $\omega$ completely? I believe the answer is yes because for the case of Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^i_{jk}$ we have explicit formulas for it in terms of the metric, and now since $\omega$ are related to $\Gamma$ in some fashion, the same ought to hold true; but now I'm not sure how to reconcile this with the above counting argument (6 unknowns vs 4 equations).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "certain $\omega^a_b$ are equal to certain functions." These are $1$-forms, not functions. So they have to be linear combinations of your $e^i$. Secondly, the structure equations *together with symmetry conditions* uniquely determine the connection $1$-forms.

Comment: @TedShifrin that was a poor phrasing on my part. I was referring to your statement "and so $\omega^0_1=e^ff'\,dt$ (and $\omega^0_j$ is a multiple of $e^j$ for $j>1$, and these will turn out to be 0 by symmetry)" and also in the next paragraph "From $de^1=0$, we see that $\omega^1_j$ is a multiple of $e^j$ for all $j$". I'm just not sure how we arrive at these conclusions. For instance, $0=de^1=-(\omega^1_0\wedge e^0+ \omega^1_1\wedge e^1+\omega^1_2\wedge e^2+\omega^1_3\wedge e^3)$ so I don't see how you conclude each $\omega^1_j$ is a multiple of $e^j$.

Comment: I can see why if $\omega^1_j$ is a multiple of $e^j$ then the summation is zero (since $e^j\wedge e^j=0$ for all $j$), but I don't see how you arrived at the converse statement. Thank you for your confirmation that the structure equations and symmetry determine the connection 1-forms, but could you elaborate how (I'm still struggling with the $6$ unknowns and 4 equations issue).

Comment: so I guess I'm overlooking some other symmetries, but I'm not sure which ones.

Comment: It all boils down to the proof of uniqueness of a torsion-free Riemannian connection. If $\sum \omega_{ij}\wedge e^j = 0$ and $\omega_{ij}=-\omega_{ji}$ for all $i,j$, then $\omega_{ij}=0$ for all $i,j$. (The first tells you that $\omega_{ij}=\sum a_{ijk}e^k$ with $a_{ijk}=a_{jik}$. The second tells you $a_{ijk}=-a_{jik}$. Now just play to get $a_{ijk}=0$ for all $i,j,k$.)

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you, I worked out the details and managed to prove that uniqueness result. This fully addresses my Q2, but I'm still having trouble understanding your solution (in the other answer) to Q1. For instance, $de^1=-\sum \omega^1_j\wedge e^j=0$ only implies that $\omega^1_j= \sum_k a^1_{jk}e^k$ where $a^1_{jk}=a^1_{kj}$, whereas you somehow concluded that each $\omega^1_j$ is a multiple of $e^j$, so $\omega^1_j= f_j\cdot e^j$ (no sum) for some functions $f_j$. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: You've disappeared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first question still boils down to the uniqueness. If one has a solution that satisfies the structure equations and (skew-) symmetry, then it must be the answer.

In the case of my solution to which you linked, remember, for starters, that $\omega_j^j=0$ for $j\ge 1$.

I really should have written that solution in a slightly different order. I agree that *a priori* we might conceivably have had, say, $\omega_3^1=e^2$. Then we'd have $\omega_2^1=e^3$ and so $\omega_1^2 = -e^3$. But we establish that $\omega_1^2$ is a multiple of $e^2$, and so this is impossible. Establishing the ones in red and imposing symmetry conditions completely fills out the table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! (I've been busy the past few days so couldn't get to this) I think now I'm starting to appreciate the role of the uniqueness, and also some of the thought process behind the "strategic guessing" (in the sense of which equations to consider first). I have written up my own answer, organizing and detailing some of my thoughts. This particular metric was motivated by the Newtonian limit of Schwarzchild metric, but I think with a few more calculations for some standard metrics encountered in GR (eg the full Schwarzchild, FRW), I'll get a better hang of this.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @Ted Shifrin's comments and answer, since we are working with the Levi-Civita connection (torsion-free, and metric-compatible) it follows that there exist unique connection 1-forms which satisfy the desired equations. Below, I shall go into more detail, but the gist is that it is much more efficient to make strategic guesses for the $\omega$'s rather than systematically calculating them, because that would be analogous to trying to calculate the Christoffel symbols using the formula $\Gamma^i_{jk}=\frac{1}{2}g^{ia}\left(\frac{\partial g_{aj}}{\partial x^{k}}+
\frac{\partial g_{ka}}{\partial x^j} - \frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial x^a}\right)$, which is painful for explicitly calculating things because many terms often turn out to be 0 after a tedious calculation. Using strategic guesses, if we find a solution for the $\omega$'s, then by the uniqueness result, that has to be it.

---

**(Existence and) Uniqueness Result.**

We first start with a pretty straightforward lemma about differential forms.

> **Lemma.**
>
> Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold, and $\{\epsilon^i\}_{i=1}^n$ a local co-frame, and $\{\omega_{ij}\}_{i,j=1}^n$ a collection of 1-forms skew-symmetric in $i,j$ and such that for all $1\leq j\leq n$, we have$\sum_{i=1}^n \omega_{ij}\wedge \epsilon^i=0$. Then, each $\omega_{ij}=0$.

The proof is pretty easy. Since the $\epsilon$'s form a co-frame, we can write $\omega_{ij}=\sum_k f_{ijk}\cdot \epsilon^k$ for some smooth functions $f_{ijk}$
($1\leq i,j,k\leq n$) which are skew-symmetric in $i,j$. Now, plugging this into our hypothesis, we have for all $j$,
\begin{align}
0&=\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_{ij}\wedge\epsilon^i\\
&=\sum_{i,k=1}^nf_{ijk}\epsilon^k\wedge \epsilon^i\\
&=\sum_{i<k} f_{ijk}\epsilon^k\wedge \epsilon^i + 
\sum_{i=k}f_{ijk}\epsilon^k\wedge \epsilon^i + 
\sum_{i>k}f_{ijk}\epsilon^k\wedge \epsilon^i\\
&=\sum_{i<k}(f_{ijk}-f_{kji})\epsilon^k\wedge \epsilon^i
\end{align}
Now, $\{\epsilon^i\}_{i=1}^n$ being a local basis of 1-forms implies that the set of 2-forms $\epsilon^k\wedge \epsilon^i$ with $1\leq i<k\leq n$ is a local basis. Hence, for all $1\leq j\leq n$ and all $1\leq i<k\leq n$, we have $f_{ijk}=f_{kij}$. But from here it clearly follows that for all $1\leq i,j,k\leq n$, we have $f_{ijk}=f_{kij}$. So, we have skew-symmetry in first two indices and symmetry in the first and last. This actually implies skew-symmetry in last two indices because $f_{ikj}=f_{jki}=-f_{kji}=-f_{ijk}$. From here, we easily see all the $f$'s vanish:
\begin{align}
f_{ijk}=f_{kji}=-f_{jki}=f_{jik}=-f_{ijk},
\end{align}
so $f_{ijk}=0$, and hence each $\omega_{ij}=0$. There may be a slightly more efficient way to shuffle the indices to arrive at this conclusion, but anyway the proof is complete.

Now, we come to the main result

> Let $(M,g)$ be an $n$-dimensional pseudo-Riemannian manifold. Then there exists a unique metric-compatible, torsion-free connection $\nabla$, such that for every smooth local 'orthonormal' coframe $\{\epsilon^1,\dots, \epsilon^n\}$, we have that the corresponding connection 1-forms satisfy $\omega_{ij}=-\omega_{ji}$ and $d\epsilon_i=-\omega_{ij}\wedge \epsilon^j$ (where $\epsilon_i=g_{ia}\epsilon^a$).

Some remarks before the proof. The condition $\omega_{ij}=-\omega_{ji}$ in an 'orthonormal' (co)frame is equivalent to metric-compatibility of the connection (simply differentiate the expression $g_{ij}=g(e_i,e_j)$ and play around with the indices, and product rule). Also, note that due to 'orthonormality', we have $g_{ij}$'s are constant and equal to $\pm\delta_{ij}$. I'm working with the lowered-indices version $\epsilon_i=g_{ia}\epsilon^a$ so that we have skew-symmetry of the $\omega$'s so that we can use the previous lemma. Next, the condition $d\epsilon=-\omega\wedge \epsilon$ with appropriate indices conveys that the connection is torsion free (with torsion, it should read $d\epsilon=-\omega\wedge \epsilon+\theta$ where $\theta$ with indices are the torsion 2-forms).

Below, I'll present two proofs for the uniqueness. The first is the slick way, invoking the lemma above. The second is more constructive/systematic/explicit and actually gives a formula which can be turned around to give a proof of existence of the Levi-Civita connection (similar to the above mentioned formula for the $\Gamma$'s).

**Proof 1. of Uniqueness**

Suppose $\omega_{ij}$ and $\eta_{ij}$ are two such connection 1-forms. Consider their difference $\zeta_{ij}=\omega_{ij}-\eta_{ij}$. Then, we have $\zeta_{ij}=-\zeta_{ji}$ and $\zeta_{ij}\wedge \epsilon^i=0$, so by the lemma each $\zeta_{ij}=0$, thereby proving the uniqueness.

**Proof 2 of Uniqueness.**

Write $\omega_{ij}=f_{ijk}\epsilon^k$ and $d\epsilon_a=\frac{1}{2}h_{ija}\epsilon^i\wedge \epsilon^j$ for some smooth functions $f,h$ which are skew-symmetric in the first two slots. Now, the structure equations $d\epsilon_a=-\omega_{ab}\wedge \epsilon^b=\omega_{ba}\wedge \epsilon^b$ say that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}h_{ija}\epsilon^i\wedge \epsilon^j&= f_{bak}\epsilon^k\wedge \epsilon^b\\
&=f_{jai}\epsilon^i\wedge \epsilon^j\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(f_{jai}-f_{iaj})\epsilon^i\wedge \epsilon^j
\end{align}
so it follows that $h_{ija}=f_{jai}-f_{iaj}$, or by some index renaming, $f_{ijk}-f_{kji}=h_{kij}$. Now, write the same thing 3 times with the indices cyclically permuted:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
f_{ijk}-f_{kji}&=h_{kij}\\
f_{jki}-f_{ikj}&=h_{ijk}\\
f_{kij}-f_{jik}&=h_{jki}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Now, take the first equation, subtract the second, add the third, and divide by 2 (and use skew-symmetry of $f$ in its first two slots) to get $f_{ijk}=\frac{1}{2}(h_{kij}-h_{ijk}+h_{jki})$. This proves that the $f$'s (and hence $\omega$'s) are uniquely determined by the $h$'s (and hence $\epsilon$'s and $d\epsilon$'s). This proves the uniqueness and gives an explicit formula.

---

Once again to emphasize, while the second proof does give us an explicit and systematic approach to calculating the $\omega$'s, it is not efficient at all. It's much better to make educated guesses for the $\omega$'s especially since in many of the hands on calculations (atleast the ones I'm trying to practice calculations with) the metric always takes a special form with certain symmetries (eg spherically symmetric), so many of the connection 1-forms will end up being zero. As a result, it's best to just look for simple solutions, and then verify in the end they're the right ones.

---

**Calculating $\omega$'s for my Question.**

We have $g_{ab}=\text{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$, and let us write $[\omega_{ij}]=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&a_1&a_2&a_3\\
-a_1&0&b_1&b_2\\
-a_2& -b_1&0&b_3\\
-a_3&-b_2&-b_3&0
\end{pmatrix}$. We thus have

\begin{align}
&\begin{cases}
\epsilon^0&=f(r)\,dt\\
\epsilon^1&=h(r)\,dr\\
\epsilon^2&=rh(r)\,d\theta\\
\epsilon^3&=rh(r)\sin\theta\,d\phi
\end{cases}
\quad \text{and}\quad
\begin{cases}
\epsilon_0&=-f(r)\,dt\\
\epsilon_1&=h(r)\,dr\\
\epsilon_2&=rh(r)\,d\theta\\
\epsilon_3&=rh(r)\sin\theta\,d\phi
\end{cases}.
\end{align}
Hence from the structural equation $d\epsilon_i=-\omega_{ij}\wedge \epsilon^j$, we have
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
d\epsilon_0= -f'(r)\,dr\wedge dt&= -(a_1\wedge \epsilon^1+a_2\wedge \epsilon^2+a_3\wedge \epsilon^3) \\
d\epsilon_1= 0&=-(-a_1\wedge \epsilon^0+b_1\wedge\epsilon^2+b_2\wedge \epsilon^3)\\
d\epsilon_2=(h(r)+rh'(r))\,dr\wedge d\theta&= -(-a_2\wedge \epsilon^0-b_1\wedge \epsilon^1+b_3\wedge \epsilon^3)\\
d\epsilon_3= (h(r)+rh'(r))\sin\theta\,dr\wedge d\phi+ rh(r)\cos\theta\,d\theta\wedge d\phi&=-(-a_3\wedge \epsilon^0-b_2\wedge \epsilon^1-b_3\wedge \epsilon^2)
\end{cases}
\end{align}

- Note that $\epsilon^0=f(r)\,dt$ involves a $dt$ term, while $d\epsilon^1,d\epsilon^2,d\epsilon^3$ do not have any $dt$ term. So, it makes sense to set $a_2=a_3=0$ (and by uniqueness this has to be correct). Also, we have $d\epsilon^0=-\left(-\frac{f'(r)}{h(r)}\,dr\right)\wedge \epsilon^0$, so we can set $a_1=-\frac{f'(r)}{h(r)}\,dr$. Then, all the equations will be satisfied by $a$.
- From the equation $d\epsilon_1=0=-(b_1\wedge\epsilon^2+b_2\wedge \epsilon^3)$, we see that
  $\begin{pmatrix}
  b_1\\
  b_2
  \end{pmatrix}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  f_{11}& f_{12}\\
  f_{12}&f_{22}
  \end{pmatrix}\cdot 
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \epsilon^2\\
  \epsilon^3
  \end{pmatrix}
  $ for some functions $f_{11},f_{12},f_{22}$.
- Going to the next equation, we have $d\epsilon_2=-(-b_1\wedge\epsilon^1+f_{12}\epsilon^2\wedge \epsilon^3)=b_1\wedge \epsilon^1-f_{12}\epsilon^2\wedge \epsilon^3$. On the other hand, we have $d\epsilon_2=-\left(1+\frac{rh'(r)}{h(r)}\right)\,d\theta\wedge \epsilon^1$. Hence, it makes sense to set $b_1=-\left(1+\frac{rh'(r)}{h(r)}\right)\,d\theta$ (which is a pure multiple of $\epsilon^2$), and hence to also set the "cross term" $f_{12}=0$. So, $b_1$ is a multiple of $\epsilon^2$ and $b_2$ is a multiple of $\epsilon^3$. The choice of setting $f_{12}=0$ is also reinforced by the fact that $d\epsilon_2$ doesn't involve any $d\phi$ (which is proportional to $\epsilon^3$) terms.
- Finally,
  \begin{align}
  d\epsilon_3&=(h(r)+rh'(r))\sin\theta\,dr\wedge d\phi+ rh(r)\cos\theta\,d\theta\wedge d\phi\\
  &=\left[-\left(1+\frac{rh'(r)}{h(r)}\right)\sin\theta\,d\phi\right]\wedge \epsilon^1+
  [-\cos\theta\,d\phi]\wedge \epsilon^2
  \end{align}
  Choose the first square bracket to be $b_2$ (which is indeed a multiple of $\epsilon^3$ as required above) and let $b_3$ be the second square bracket.

Summarizing, we have
\begin{align}
[\omega_{ij}]&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0& -\frac{f'(r)}{h(r)}\,dt& 0 & 0\\
\frac{f'(r)}{h(r)}\,dt & 0 & -\left(1+\frac{rh'(r)}{h(r)}\right)\,d\theta&
-\left(1+\frac{rh'(r)}{h(r)}\right)\sin\theta\,d\phi\\
0& \left(1+\frac{rh'(r)}{h(r)}\right)\,d\theta & 0 & -\cos\theta\,d\phi\\
0& \left(1+\frac{rh'(r)}{h(r)}\right)\sin\theta\,d\phi & \cos\theta\,d\phi & 0
\end{pmatrix}\\\\
\text{and}\quad 
[\omega^i_{\,j}]&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0& \frac{f'(r)}{h(r)}\,dt& 0 & 0\\
\frac{f'(r)}{h(r)}\,dt & 0 & -\left(1+\frac{rh'(r)}{h(r)}\right)\,d\theta&
-\left(1+\frac{rh'(r)}{h(r)}\right)\sin\theta\,d\phi\\
0& \left(1+\frac{rh'(r)}{h(r)}\right)\,d\theta & 0 & -\cos\theta\,d\phi\\
0& \left(1+\frac{rh'(r)}{h(r)}\right)\sin\theta\,d\phi & \cos\theta\,d\phi & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
As a sanity check, $[\omega_{ij}]$ is indeed skew-symmetric and we can quickly verify that it satisfies the structure equations, so this is the correct answer. The matrix for $\omega^i_{\,j}$ is obtained by multiplying row 0 of $[\omega_{ij}]$ by a factor of $-1$ (due to Lorentz signature $(-1,1,1,1)$).

Having found the $\omega^i_{\,j}$ we can then go on to calculate the curvature 2-forms and so on.

Comment: Could you expand on how you got the $e_i$ for $i = 0,1,2,3$? I would expect that the bases $e^i$ and $e_i$  are dual and such $e^i e_j = \delta^i_j$ but from your solutions we get, for example, $e^0 e_0 = - f^2(r) dt^2$.

Comment: @Nitaaa in my notation $\{\epsilon^0,\epsilon^1,\epsilon^2,\epsilon^3\}$ and $\{\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3\}$ are both coframes, but they’re not dual to each other (we’re talking about coframes, so it wouldn’t make much sense to call them dual). They’re defined such that $\epsilon^i=\sum_{j=0}^3g^{ij}\epsilon_j$. In our case, $g^{ij}=g_{ij}=\text{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$, so to convert from one to the other, we just change the sign of the $0^{th}$ covector.

Comment: I introduced both of them because for some purposes one set of coframes is better, while for other purposes, the other set is better suited.