# Riemann Curvature of Schwarzschild with curvature 2-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, curvature, general-relativity

I have been studying Chapter 14 of Misner, Thorne, Wheeler's Gravitation, in particular the method of computing curvature using exterior differential forms. Is there a reference that computes the curvature of Schwarzschild using this method? There is an exercise in the chapter in the same chapter, exercise 14.13 that states this problem and provides an answer. However, it would be very helpful for me to see the actual derivation of the solution.

Comment: Box 14.5 in MTW goes in detail through a similar exercise for the Fiedmann cosmology. I believe this book is the best reference. A related question is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398421/reading-off-connection-1-forms-from-cartans-structural-equation-de-omega-wed). You may want to try MTW ex. 14.13 and post in detail where you get stuck.

Comment: I was the one who asked the question linked above (if you choose the $f$ and $h$ there appropriately then the metric is the Newtonian limit of Schwarzschild). I included the full calculation of the connection 1-forms for this case. The calculation for the full Schwarzschild metric shouldn't be much harder. Once you find the 1-forms $\omega$'s, calculating the curvature is then completely mechanical and routine $\Omega^i_{\,j}=d\omega^i_{\,j}+\omega^i_{\,a}\wedge \omega^a_{\,j}$.